# The class "java.lang.ref.Finalizer", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 6,125,536 (11.96%) bytes

Tags: java

Today I found my app runing by Java 11 in CentOS 7.x use 500MB+ memory, but I configure the XMX is 256MB. This is my startup script:

```
nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -jar \
  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=0.0.0.0:5019 \
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/apps/dolphin-post/ \
  ${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME} >> /dev/null &
```

Then I dump the memory `jmap -dump:format=b,file=./my.dump 24354` and loaded into [Memory Analysis Tool](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Shows this report:

```
The class "java.lang.ref.Finalizer", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 6,125,536 (11.96%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.ref.Finalizer" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
java.lang.ref.Finalizer
```

I have no idea where is going wrong. what should I do to find out the problem? In my app, I have not implement the Finalizer by myself.

Comment: I read the question, but after that I still do not know how to find the problem and fix it. I am try to figure out where is going wrong.

Comment: Max memory = [-Xmx] + number_of_threads * [-Xss], try using jvisualvm - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html.